# python web bot selenium can not get it to postug though

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Hi there I am trying to make my webdriver open and 
execute  code in posting on facebook account and I can not 
figure out why my button tag and post text will not work please 
help me.

this is the part that is not working everything else works though
and it keeps saying button cannot be clicked

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
for button in buttons:
    if 'Post' in button.text:
        button.click()
    driver.quit()
```

> Blockquote

```
#imports webdriver from selenium 
from selenium import webdriver

#creates web driver
driver= webdriver.Chrome()


#creates window for facebook
driver.get("https://facebook.com")



#finds the element with name and enters email 
element = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
element.send_keys("someemail@gmail.com")

#finds the element by name and enters password
el2= driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
el2.send_keys("somePassword")


#finds button to log on and clicks it
el3 = driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_b")
el3.click()

#finds xpath to put message in tab window for posting
el3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@name='xhpc_message']")
el3.send_keys("Ryan's Python bot was here 5/19/2020")

#waits for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


#clicks button to Post but does not work
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
    for button in buttons:
        if 'Post' in button.text:
            button.click()
driver.quit()
```